# Installed KDE - not in the list

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I have Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus and I installed kubuntu-desktop.

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

Now there is no KDE in the login screen selection. Just Gnome classic, Gnome-wayland (which does not work because 15.081410 rc.local[1923]: Error opening display!)
MATE (the only one usable)
Plasma (black desktop with a few tray icons and no usable panels...)

How do I make KDE appear there as well?

```
vitas@vitas-ThinkPad-T460:~$ dpkg -l *kubuntu*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  kubuntu-defaul <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  kubuntu-deskto 1.338        amd64        Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook sy
ii  kubuntu-driver 15.10ubuntu3 amd64        Driver Manager for Kubuntu
un  kubuntu-firefo <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  kubuntu-notifi 15.10ubuntu2 amd64        Kubuntu system notification helpe
ii  kubuntu-settin 1:16.04ubunt all          Settings and artwork for the Kubu
ii  kubuntu-web-sh 15.04ubuntu1 all          web shortcuts for Kubuntu, Ubuntu
ii  libkubuntu1    15.04ubuntu2 amd64        library for Kubuntu platform inte
ii  plymouth-theme 1:16.04ubunt all          graphical boot animation and logg
ii  plymouth-theme 1:16.04ubunt all          graphical boot animation and logg
```

BTW How the heck do I make my post preserve all line breaks and not just some? This is not very readable. I am sorry, but I did not figure out how to fix that...

Comment: Plasma is the kubuntu-desktop.

Comment: Aha :D The thing is that I tried to install it a long time ago. It did not work and I forgot meanwhile. Any idea how to fix it? As I said - black background, few scattered tray icons in the middle and nothing else... It's been some time and I thought they might have fixed it already.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I never installed it as an additional DE. I do use a few KDE apps though (and its dependencies). Perhaps reinstalling the meta-package (with --reinstall) will bring something that's missing.

Comment: Which meta-package you mean? Kubuntu-desktop?

Comment: Yes, of course. It's a meta-package because it has no content in itself but lists and installs others.

Comment: wow this seems to have fixed it and KDE now works! I would never have figured this out though, because it does not make much sense :-\ Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to assure the correct and complete installation of all the packages required, use the following command to reinstall the `kubuntu-desktop` meta-package:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop
```